# publish mvc4 web application in folder, then upload it to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Made a simple web application using mvc 4.

As we know we can publish asp.net web applications to a local system folder and then we can upload it to server. I did it several times while using 3 tier and n-tier application.

But I didn't find any luck publishing mvc4 application to a folder in my local system

Please tell me if anyone knows how to do it.

Comment: right click on your solution -> publish -> create a new profil -> choose filesystem under Publish method -> choose the path.-> publish.

Comment: No luck , i found that previously, actually it asking several thins like serviceURL,site/application...no browising option for folder in which i want to publish..some other thing ?

Comment: Publishing an Asp.net MVC project means: 
- publish project to local folder
- copy the folder content in the IIS website folder (i assume you already have an IIS website configured)

Comment: no i never used iis, i work in small company...they publish websites in local folder and then we upload it to server.

Comment: you are choosing WebDeploy,choose Filesystem and then proceed

Comment: why you want to prefer publish mvc code before uploading files at online.. Instead you can simply upload all the `.dll` files and your views and your scripting with images..